# Mercurial: Resync working directory with .hgignore file

Tags: mercurial, hgignore

I just opened up a project that had the .hgignore file set up entirely wrong. I have fixed it to what it should be, and now I have to remove all the stuff that it was previously not ignoring and now should. Maybe its just early in the morning, but any way to do that other than manually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(requires Mercurial >= 1.9)

> $ hg forget "set:hgignore() and not ignored()"

see hg help [filesets](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#filesets) for more

Comment: ah, I'm on 1.7.2 - any solution for that?

Comment: upgrade? :) using hg alone, I don't think so. what OS are you on?

Comment: Windows 7, installed via TortoiseHg. Although I mostly command-line everything, I use the gui stuff just often enough not to want to mess with it.

Comment: @George: well I possibly could try to whip something up if you had a decent shell, but in this case I'd suggest you upgrade.

Comment: Windows 7 includes Powershell, but the easiest path is still upgrading Mercurial.

Comment: hmm, I know PS pretty well, is there an hg command to evaluate hgignore and show what files WOULD be ignored or would I just have to manually parse it?

Comment: Yeah there is a command in hg, the one Idan answered with. Otherwise you're stuck transforming glob patterns into regex (probably) and filtering a list of all files with those patterns, then intersecting that list of ignored files with the list of tracked files (`hg manifest` would help with that).